# How to convert an MS Access "IIF" query to a Sql Server query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

```
IIf(  ((Year([f_periodo])*12)+Month([f_periodo]))
     -((Year(Date())*12)+Month(Date()))<0,1,IIf(  ((Year([f_periodo])*12)+Month([f_periodo]))
                                                 -((Year(Date())*12)+Month(Date()))=0,2,3)
    ) AS sts_exigible
```

Comment: SQL-Server doesn't have IIF, the equivalent is a case statement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: Show us what you tried; this isn't a programming service.

Comment: @KevinRaffay Not true [Logical Functions - IIF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). To the OP, however, you're using 2008, so look up CASE (Transact-SQL). Try to solve the problem yourself first, rather than not performing any research yourself. A simple Google would have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
select case
when (datepart(year, [f_periodo]) * 12 + datepart(month, [f_periodo])) - 
(datepart(year, getdate()) * 12 + datepart(month, getdate())) < 0 then 1
when (datepart(year, [f_periodo]) * 12 + datepart(month, [f_periodo])) - 
(datepart(year, getdate()) * 12 + datepart(month, getdate())) = 0 then 2
else 3
end as sts_exigible
```

Comment: Second then result should be 2, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
sign(datediff(month, f_periodno, current_timestamp)) + 2;
```

Try this out:

```
declare @f_periodno datetime;

set @f_periodno = '20240101';
select sign(datediff(month, @f_periodno, current_timestamp)) + 2;

set @f_periodno = dateadd(day, -3, current_timestamp);
select sign(datediff(month, @f_periodno, current_timestamp)) + 2;

set @f_periodno = '20140101';
select sign(datediff(month, @f_periodno, current_timestamp)) + 2;
```

I agree that it's best to search for the answer yourself. If I didn't enjoy reverse engineering and simplifying your expression I would have probably passed on spending my time to help out. Good luck.